# Does exist any IP-KVM that connects to motherboards pinheads with powerbutton, reset, etc.?

Tags: electrical-power, colocation, keyboard-video-mouse

Exists couple of "servers" based on usual consumers motherboard, without any remote capabilities.

Is there any kvm with modules, that connects to pin header of motherboard, where powerbutton, reset button, hdd led located and allows to remotely "push" those buttons ?

Thanks

Comment: Never heard of something like that (and as shopping question it would be OT). Anyway, I used to retrofit old equipment without reasonable IP-KVM and IPMI with external IP-KVM and remote controlled PDUs. It wasn't exactly the same but the essential functionality was there.

Comment: Yes, problem here lies in that i will be required to change whole cabinet with mine PDU ... i'm not sure if this worth it , so looking for alternative

Comment: Capabilities like this are one good reason to never use consumer grade hardware as a "server".

Comment: @MichaelHampton you right and wrong. There many other reasons to use consumer grade hardware, and its not because of price at all.

Comment: Supermicro, American Megatrends, and others make OOB cards.  It really boils down to compatibility with your motherboards/hardware.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at HP/IBM/Dell servers they have out of band management capabilities (such as HP's iLO, Dell's DRAC) that let you do all of this without having to wire the pins up - it's all built it. I'm unaware of any actual KVMs that let you do this however.

Comment: I'm aware about ILO/iDrac, but i talking about "consumers" mother board...

This idea is pretty good and doesn't hearing like smth extraordinary hard to realise, so i thought that this may exist =)

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the point of Serverfault - it's not about consumer products, but professional ones - please read our help pages before posting again as there are other SE sites where this kind of question is more appropriate.

Comment: So, you trying to say that "consumers" motherboard can't be used anywhere in any other place, except home PC?
Its not about grade of product that used, but about solution, that allows to use benefits that this type of hardware brings.
It have its own cons, such as no remote capabilities, and thus it need a solution, allows to control it remotely.